# robot description in turtlebot

Tags: ros, robot-model, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to push everithing related to my robot under the name of the robot, but when it comes to the topic robot_description I can't, the description keeps the original tree for the transform and does not go under the tf_prefix or the ns that I give. Actually the parameter goes under the ns as the new parameter is turtelbot2/robot_description.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/eb98b1032146dec8e278d00ef714924c

as you can se the names of the parts of the robot are not turtlebot2/base_link is just base_link.

Is there any chance to push them under a parameter similar to tf_prefix?

Thanks!

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12736/robot-description-in-turtlebot/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is another way than creating two different robot descriptions to prefix the link names. I'm not sure if that's necessary though. The robot_state_publisher accepts the tf_prefix parameter and will prefix the links with it when it publishes the TF tree. As long as all your turtlebots are identical, you can use one robot_description parameter and several robot_state_publishers with different tf_prefix parameters. If you put robot_description into a namespace, you need to set the parameter robot_description of the robot_state_publisher as well.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2